# skip the result in a search using suite script 2.0

Tags: suitescript2.0

To skip result range in my script, When I created a search using suite script 2.0 . I don't want to use `getRange({---})` function. How can I do it?

```
var searchresult = mySearch.run().getRange({start: 0, end: 50});
```

Comment: format your code

Comment: How can I format bro.Please show me your advise.